# I want to add www prefix in my sub domain

Tags: domains

I have a domain name `www.example.com`. I have a sub domain like this `image.example.com`.

When, I am trying to open `www.image.example.com`, it is not opening.

My requirements is to open sub domain adding `www`.

Domain and sub domain are in different servers.

Answer (score 3):

The domain name typically is `domainname.something`.

Anything before the `domainname` is the subdomain.

So, `image.domainname.com` is the same as `www.domainname.com` in that both are subdomains of the same domain. This is also true of all sub-subdomains or sub-sub-subdomains etc.

You need to set a subdomain up as `www.image` and then point it to the relevant server. On your server where the records are kept (A records), set up a subdomain called `image` (as you have) and then another subdomain called `www` but point this to the `image` sub directory. Or, see if you can use a period (.) within the sub domain name (depends on the software used to create the subdomain). Alternatively, look at the C Name and create it there.

Answer (score 2):

`www` is the commonly accepted practice for designating that specific URL's serves up web traffic, there is no rule that says your URL have to begin with `www`.

Domains consist of a few parts:

```
http://www.image.example.com.
```

The trailing dot is intentional, all addresses are understood to end with a period but technology lets us omit it for convenience.

- `com.` - Top Level Domain
- `example.` - Your domain
- `image.` - Sub domain
- `www.` - Sub domain
- and so on...

As an analogy, think of it as a folder on your computer for example, but having it written it down in the opposite direction. `C:\com\example\image\www`

Once you have access to the folder `example`, you can do what ever you want with any/all folders inside it (regardless of how deep they are) but you don't have access to `com` nor the root drive.

When you register for a specific domain you typically have full control over all sub domains. If a registrar ever makes you pay for a sub domain I'd immediately switch to some one else. In this case if you owned `example.com` you could do what ever you want with its subdomains. Heck you could do `this.is.my.awesome.site.example.com` if you wanted.

That being said, fewer subdomains is generally better when it comes to people having to actually type them in. Most places would have both `example.com` and `www.example.com` point to the same site, and just include them both options to cover all their bases. But nothing is stopping you from making your domain names whatever you want. If you're using an online provider like GoDaddy or the like, they'll likely have an built in DNS management module that will let you configure your own DNS records. You'll have to add the subdomain there first, then you'll need to configure your website to respond to requests made for that specific URL. Typically referred to as the *bindings*. Once those two parts are done you should be able to hit the site using your new URL.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to set up an A record for www.image in your DNS records. Alternatively, you could set up a record for *.image.

Also, you may need to update the configuration of the web server to make sure it is also listening for requests for those host names.